# Test context menu appears after firing right click event in React Testing Library

Tags: contextmenu, react-testing-library

I would like to test that a context menu has appeared after firing off a right click event with React Testing Library.

I don't know if there are timing difficulties or not, but the following test fails because it can't find the autoscale button (in the context menu) that should exist after a right click:

```
   it('a context menu appears after a right click', async () => {
      model = await makeModel(
         ['Channel 1'], {
            laneHeaders: 'none'
         }
      );

      const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(
         <DataPreview
            model={model}
         />
      );

      // node dealing with the right click event
      const eventNode = getByTestId('data-preview-container');

      // see https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events
      const rightClickEvent = createEvent.click(eventNode, { button: 2 });
      fireEvent.click(eventNode, rightClickEvent);

      //Error: Unable to find an element with the text: Autoscale.
      const autoScaleContextMenuButton = getByText('Autoscale');

      expect(
         autoScaleContextMenuButton
      ).not.toBeNull();
   });
```

Comment: Did you try to use `fireEvent` instead of `fireEvent.click` since you're creating the event?

Answer (score 2):

```
fireEvent.contextMenu(eventNode)
```

works for me

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
// get the test component
const testComp = screen.getByTestId(some_test_id_here);
// create a contextMenu event
const contextMenuEvent = createEvent.contextMenu(testComp);
// fire the event with the contextMenu event
fireEvent(testComp, contextMenuEvent);
// do more checking
```

If you don't need to check the context menu event, i.e., propagation, prevent default, bubble, etc, you can omit the event creation and call `fireEvent` directly.

Reference: [React - Jest - Test preventDefault Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139857/8851585)