# React - Jest - Test preventDefault Action

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I don't know how to test key down event & prevent default. Test reached code but `preventDefault` has never been called: `Received number of calls: 0`

**React Component** - **App.js**

```
  const onKeyDown = e => {
      console.log("==== TEST REACHED HERE ====")
      e.preventDefault(); // NEVER CALLED ???
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    return () =>
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
  }, []);
```

**Unit test**

```
it("should prevent default action on key down", () => {
   const { getByRole } = render(<App {...props} />);
   const grid = getByRole("app");
   const mockEvent = { preventDefault: jest.fn() };
   fireEvent.keyDown(grid, mockEvent);
   expect(mockEvent.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Is `TEST REACHED HERE` logged before the test fails?

Comment: Can you provide the JSX returned in your `App.js` component?

Comment: You just saved me so much time.  Thank you for keeping it simple!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that you [can not mock `preventDefault`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/572) property of the event with react testing library.

Under the hook, `fireEvent` is calling [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), so you can take advantage of the fact that calling `event.preventDefault` returns false if the event is cancelled:

```
it("should prevent default action on key down", () => {
   const { getByRole } = render(<App {...props} />);
   const grid = getByRole("app");
   const isPrevented = fireEvent.keyDown(grid);
   expect(isPrevented).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will use this technique to test my Svelte app.

Comment: It is not the explicit way of checking preventDefault.

Answer (score 24):

I found a more explicit way than accepted answer. You can use [`createEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#createeventeventname) from 'react-testing-library' to manually create the event before firing it.

```js
it("should prevent default action on key down", () => {
  const { getByRole } = render(<App {...props} />);
  const grid = getByRole("app");
  const keyDownEvent = createEvent.keyDown(grid);
   
  fireEvent(grid, keyDownEvent);
   
  expect(keyDownEvent.defaultPrevented).toBe(true);
});
```

I think this method can be reused to test other things than defaultPrevented !

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. It is more explicit and worked fine for me

Comment: This one didn't work for me when testing mouseDown event

Comment: My bad, it worked fine (can't edit previous comment).

Comment: could this maybe be an old API?  createEvent does not seem to be a thing

Comment: @RClaven the hyperlink to createEvent documentation was broken in my answer. I just fixed it.

Comment: Thanks man, that helped, was about to giving up. ;)
Should be the accepted answer imho